# Adding an object that has two separate Strings to an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have done some googling and read through my texts but I can only seem to find how to add a single string to an element of an arrayList i.e. arrayList.add("adding this new string");

as each element is an object, I need to store two strings in each element.
For example I have a txt file with the below already stored:

> Programming in Java: ITC206
> IT Helpdesk: ITC232
> Cyber Ethics: ITC311

When I read the file and add it to an ArrayList it tells me I have 3 elements in the list, one for each line, each line consisting of two strings.

When I try and add a new line in, I can't seem to add two separate strings, one for the course name and one for the course code.

I have tried this manually i.e. `arrayList.add("IT", "ITC000");` but it assumes I am trying to specify the element and tells me I can't convert the string ("IT") to an int.

below is the code I have written. all works fine until I hit the subjectList.add to add the new line/element to the list.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create array list        
    ArrayList<String> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // inport scanner
    
    //read objects from List of Subjects txt file
    try (BufferedReader list = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("ListofSubjects.txt"))) {
        String listLine;
        while ((listLine = list.readLine()) != null) {
            subjectList.add(listLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) { // catch any exceptions 
    }
    
    //get new subject name and code 
    System.out.println("Enter the name of your new Subject: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the code for your new Subject: ");
    String code = input.nextLine();
    
    //Subject constructor with two string arg from Subject class
    Subject newSubject = new Subject(name, code);
    
    subjectList.add(newSubject); 
    // I want the element to hold both the name and code
    //like the other lines of the list but get error
    
       
    System.out.println("List Size? " + subjectList.size());
    System.out.println("the list now has: " + subjectList.toString());

}
```

Maybe I don't need to add these separately, however I need to be able to check the subject name, and the code separately, so figured this would be easier done if they are separate strings in the element.

Comment: Maybe I need to just add them both as a single string but backwards, i.e. ITC206 Programming in Java, then when I want to check the details for the code or the name, I just split it based on the first 6 characters of the string (the code). I would need to add the string to its own array of characters, then check that way maybe....

Comment: You can create a new list  ArrayList<Subject > subjectObj = new ArrayList<>(); and assign subjectObj .add(newSubject);

Comment: Look at the List interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html Use one add() call per element. So if you want to add two strings, call add() two times. The other add() method with two parameters has a different purpose. The first parameter is always and int. This is the reason for your compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add both attributes seperatly.

```
subjectList.add(newSubject.getName()); 
subjectList.add(newSubject.getCode());
```

Or if you need to do it in one call:

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(newSubject.getName(), newSubject.getCode()));
```

You could also try to create a List only for Subject objects, but when you need to change your approach to add your listLines.

```
List<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // inport scanner

//read objects from List of Subjects txt file
try (BufferedReader list = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("ListofSubjects.txt"))) {
    String listLine;
    while ((listLine = list.readLine()) != null) {
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        subject.setName(listLine); // or setCode()
        subjectList.add(subject);
    }
} catch (IOException e) { // catch any exceptions 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! list.addAll(Arrays.asList(newSubject.getName(), newSubject.getCode())); this seems to be the way to go or close to. I might need to tweek a few things because it added the subject name twice as separate elements, but no subject code with them.

Comment: You can use a Set to prevent doubled values.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to mix what your list contains.

For the stuff you read from the file you want the list to hold a single `String` with all data.

For the new subject you want to add an object of your custom `Subject` class.

You can't do that <sup>*</sup>. Your list is *either* a `List<String>` or a `List<Subject>`.

My suggestions is to have the more-explicit type (since you already have a `Subject` class) and use `List<Subject>`. First you must change the declaration of your `subjectList`:

```
ArrayList<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

That means you'll need to modify the code that reads from the file to construct `Subject` objects as well:

```
try (BufferedReader list = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("ListofSubjects.txt"))) {
    String listLine;
    while ((listLine = list.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lineParts = listLine.split(":", 2);
        Subject subject = new Subject(lineParts[0].trim(), lineParts[1].trim());
        subjectList.add(subject);
    }
}
```

This way later on in your code you can be sure that `subjectList` contains `Subject` objects only, no matter if you read them from the file or added them later.

<sup>* actually you can and before generics that was even somewhat common, but it's a terrible idea and among other things generics were introduced to get rid of inter-mixed collections.</sup>

Comment: This actually looks like it is going to work but I get an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"
and I am not great an understanding error's so not sure whats causing this. There are no errors showing in the code, only once its run.

Comment: That means that for at least one line `split()` doesn't find the separator and thus returns an array of size 1. Try debugging which line that is (either with a real debugger or by simply printing `lineParts` using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineParts));` before the `Subject subject ...` line (you'll still get the exception but should find out what the problematic line is).